# Which are the "Mode" requirements for a wireless card to work with hostapd?

Tags: wifi, hostapd, access-point

I need to transform a Linux box to an Access Point via hostapd.

I've already tested it with an Atheros AR9485 wireless card, which supports AP Mode and Master Mode, and it works great.

Unfortunately this card is not available anymore; the vendor proposed to replace it with a wireless card that has the Atheros AR9382 chipset and supports AP Mode; Master Mode is not mentioned explicitly in the specs. Unfortunately it is not possible to test the card before buying it.

[An answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319838/failed-to-set-interface-wlan0-into-ap-mode-intel-centrino-n1000-wireless) suggests that both modes need to be supported, but as far as I remember all docs concerning hostapd only mention AP Mode.

So, for a Wi-Fi card to work as an AP via hostapd, is it necessary for it to support both AP Mode and Master Mode, or just AP Mode will work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer to note that the Atheros AR9382 chipset card worked fine as an Access Point.  So I suppose that AP Mode is all that's needed.  Unfortunately I haven't more than an empirical answer at the moment.